# Create index for huge query in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following huge request :

```
SELECT TOP (100000) 
    B.UserId AS [UserId], B.ProfileId AS [ProfileId] 
FROM 
    tBounce AS B
JOIN
    tBounceType AS BT ON BT.Id = B.BounceTypeId
WHERE
    BT.IsHard = 1 AND B.IsProcessedByAutoUnsubscriber = 0
GROUP BY 
    B.UserId, B.ProfileId
HAVING
    count(*) > 2
```

The `tBounce` table contains billions of records, which columns do I need to include in an index ? Need i add grouping fields as well ?

Comment: You should have a ORDER BY in there,also learn about the execution plan and post it in the question

Comment: There is a main part of execution plan : http://prntscr.com/7af1b2 , but this query sometimes can works extremly slow. What could be a reason of that behaviour ?

Comment: If is is sometime slow then most likely locks.  Try with (nolock)

Comment: Your execution plan already has a suggestion as to the index to use. I would strongly recommend that you add a filter to your index with `IsProcessedByAutoUnsubscriber  = 0`.

Comment: Came here to suggest a filtered index, but was beaten to the punch by @ZoffDino. The only caveat would be that the percentage of rows that qualify for the where clause should be small or it's not worth maintaining the index for the benefit you'd get out of it.